# Macbook Wifi Problem with Ubuntu

Tags: macbook

I installed Linux on a 2009 Macbook.  It says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found."  The computer has the following processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P7450 @ 2.13GHz × 2

None of the solutions I have seen have worked.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Also, which MacBook do you have? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_(2006%E2%80%932012)  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Second_generation_(Unibody)